# Apache Airflow not able to create pod using kubernetesPodOperator

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, airflow

I have deployed Spark k8s operator(provided by google) and Apache Airflow on same k8s cluster but when i try to create spark job using airflow, It's not creating spark driver and executor. And also I'm not able to see the logs of task pods created by airflow.
To create a spark job I have added a yaml variable in dag which is copied into a file in kubernetes pod executor block.

my Dag.py file:

````
```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from kubernetes.client.models import V1VolumeMount, V1Volume
import yaml

default_args = {
  'owner': 'airflow',
  'depends_on_past': False,
  'start_date': datetime(2023, 4, 30),
  'email_on_failure': False,
  'email_on_retry': False,
  'retries': 1,
  'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
  'run_spark_on_k8s',
  default_args=default_args,
  schedule_interval=None
)



spark_application_yaml = '''
apiVersion: sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: my-spark-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: Python
  mode: cluster
  pythonVersion: '3'
  image: 'gcr.io/spark-operator/spark-py:v3.1.1'
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: local:///opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py
  sparkVersion: '3.1.1'
  restartPolicy:
    type: OnFailure
    onFailureRetries: 3
    onFailureRetryInterval: 10s
    onSubmissionFailureRetries: 5
    onSubmissionFailureRetryInterval: 20s
  dynamicAllocation:
    enabled: true
    initialExecutors: 2
    minExecutors: 2
    maxExecutors: 20
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: '1200m'
    memory: '512m'
    labels:
      version: '3.1.1'
    serviceAccount: my-release-spark
    podName: spark-pi-driver
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 1
    memory: '512m'
    labels:
      version: '3.1.1'
    serviceAccount: my-release-spark
'''

spark_application = yaml.safe_load(spark_application_yaml)

volume_mounts = [V1VolumeMount(name='spark-volume', mount_path='/spark_job/app')]

volumes = [
    V1Volume(name='spark-volume', empty_dir={}, config_map=None, host_path=None, persistent_volume_claim=None,
             secret=None, downward_api=None, projected=None)
]


launch_spark_app = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id='launch_spark_app',
    name='spark-on-k8s',
    namespace='default',
    image='bitnami/kubectl:latest',
    cmds=['/bin/bash', '-c'],
    arguments=[
        'echo starting spark application', 
        f'echo \'{spark_application_yaml}\' > /spark_job/app/application.yaml',
        'cat /spark_job/app/application.yaml',
        'kubectl apply -f /spark_job/app/application.yaml'
    ],
    volume_mounts=volume_mounts,
    volumes=volumes,
    get_logs=True,
    dag=dag
) 
    ```
````